# How to cache the css and script files on browser, And use it in all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

How to avoid loading the css and Javascript files again and again in all pages? I want to cache my script files and css files. Then i want to use it from browser in all my pages.

So that it increases my application performance.

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers automatically cache based on the Cache Control Headers in HTTP.
You should configure your webserver to set these if they haven't already.

http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS and JS files are cached automatically by default. if you want to increase page load time use Ajax or some javascript template libraries.

Comment: How to use the cached css and js file in my pages. Please can you share the sample code ?

Comment: user3165441, it is cached automatically.

Comment: How to use cached js files?

Comment: We don't have to use anything. when you use <script src="....">, the browser checks whether it is in cache, if yes it will use it otherwise it will download from web server.